# Spring MVC is not logging the error stackTrace

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc 4.3 application.

I defined a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

```
<bean id="SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="warnLogCategory" value="myuncaughtException"/>
</bean>
```

When an exception occurs a default page with the error message + stack trace is displayed.

But in the log file I only have a single line :

```
 WARN  http-nio-9090-exec-13 uncaughtException - Resolved exception caused by handler execution: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The stackTrace is absent which is making very difficult to know where is crashed (and in production the stack trace on the error page is not displayed).

I found where Spring is logging (in AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver) :

```
protected void logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (this.warnLogger != null && this.warnLogger.isWarnEnabled()) {
            this.warnLogger.warn(buildLogMessage(ex, request));
        }
    }

    
protected String buildLogMessage(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "Resolved exception caused by handler execution: " + ex;
}
```

And the stackTrace is not included leaving no option to do it...

How can I make Spring log the stacktrace (in both the html view and the log file) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question make use of `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` class. This is a Spring Framework class but it is public and can be extended.

**Proposed solution**

Extend the above class as `MyExceptionResolver` and override the *logException* method like:

```
protected String buildLogMessage(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "Resolved exception caused by handler execution: " + ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Adjust the XML configuration accordingly.

```
<bean id="MyExceptionResolver" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a easy solution just by overiding SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

```
public class MySimpleMappingExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {
    
    private Logger log;

    @Override
    protected void logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        //super.logException(ex, request);
        log.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void setWarnLogCategory(String loggerName) {     
        super.setWarnLogCategory(loggerName);
        log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName);
    }

}
```

Then I use my own implementation where I can log as I want.

Answer (score -1):

Don't add the exception to the string. Instead, pass the exception as an argument to the logger methods.

When you concatenate the exception into the string, using '+', you are calling the `toString` method on the exception, which returns the name like you are seeing in your method.

If you instead do it like this, it will log the stack trace as you want:

```
warnLogger.warn("Resolved exception caused by handler execution:", ex);
```

Comment: yes, but this code is inside Spring that the problem :(

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that.